# What is the appropriate weight?

Tags: integer, partitioning

I have a question in my mind. I do not know where to start.
Can anyone guide me a little?

A positive integer can be partitioned, for example, the number 7 can be partitioned into the following:

7=6+1 ,  7=5+2   , 7=3+3+1,...

suppose that

n_k:=the number of times that a number is used.
( For example, in partitioning  7 = 3 + 2 + 2, we have n_2 = 2 and  n_3 = 1)

suppose K as largest number in every partiotioning , For example, in partitioning  7 = 3 + 2 + 2, K is 3 , and in the  partitioning  7 = 5 + 2  , we have K=5 .

suppose that P1  and P2  are two arbitrary partitions.

n_k:=the number of times that a number is used in partitioning P1 .
n'_k:=the number of times that a number is used in partitioning P2  .

K as largest number in every partiotioning.

if The largest number in both partitions be  the same.( I mean, for P1  and P2 , the value of K is the same. For example,P1 be  12 = 5 + 5 + 2 and  P2 be 12 = 5 + 4 + 3 in both partitions K is 5.)

What is the appropriate positive  weight (W_k) for two arbitrary partitions to maintain the following relationship?

if  n_K >  n'_K    then

W_2 n_2 + W_3 n_3+...+ W_K n_K  >   W_2 n'_2 + W_3 n'_3+...+ W_K n'_K

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

Wk=(number+1)^(k−1), interpreting the frequency representation of the partition as a number in a base which is guaranteed to be larger than any of the digits.